# Graph of a polytope as intersection of closed halfspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to build a polytope using implicit inequalities, one of the examples I found was the following

$$P=\{(x, y, z): x+y+z \leq 4, x+y \geq 3, z \leq 1, 1 \leq y \leq 2 \}$$

From this we have that $x+y+z \leq 4$, $x+y \geq 3$ and $z \leq 1$ are the implicit equalities in the system of inequalities that defining P.

My question is, graphically is it possible to obtain this polytope? I have tried Wolfram|Alpha but it has not been possible, any suggestions?

Remember that...

We say that $a^{i}x \leq b_{i}$ is an implicit equality of $Ax \leq b$ if an H-polytope $P$ is contained in the hyperplane $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}: a^{i}x=b_{i} \}$.

1. We denote by $A^{=}x \leq b^{=}$ the system containing all implicit equalities of $Ax \leq b$.
2. We denote by $A^{\le }x \leq b^{ \le}$ the system containing all remaining inequalities of $Ax \leq b$.

Additionally, do you know of any example of a polytope that is described by its implicit equalities?

Comment: See "worked examples" in this [document](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH5801/12/12_3_rep_of_poly.html) connecting the inequalities characterization with the convex hull characterization.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for this; could we say, using the solution of worked example 1, that (3) and (4) are implicit equalities?

Comment: Yes, implicit (in)equalities...